# validation on uniqueness record on the association relation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have some query, like a :

```
Assignment.where(date: "2019-07-01")
         .includes(crews: :truck)
         .where.not({ crews: {truck_id: nil}})
         .count
#=>  2 records.
```

Here's an example with contain:

```
Assignment.where(date: "2019-07-01")
         .includes(crews: :truck)
         .where.not({ crews: {truck_id: nil}})
         .distinct.pluck('trucks.name')

#=> ["Mercedes", "BMW"]
```

I want to check for the uniqueness of truck_id in Assignment.where(date: "2019-07-01")
And in order to attach an existing truck_id to another Assignment object, validation was triggered.

And a message pops up that you cannot add, since such a Truck object is already attached to one of the Assignment on the day that is specified in .where

Please tell me how to implement it correctly. Thank.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't want to write a validate method, you can still use uniqueness options.Use conditional option to tell which rows should do the validation.

```
validates :truck_id, uniqueness: true, if: Proc.new { |assignment| assignment.on_specified_day? }
```